# Java for and while loops do no work as expected

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

This piece of code (Java) does not work, and I can't figure out why.

```
int[][] arr = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};

for(int a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
   for(int b = 0; b < arr[a].length;) {
      int c = 1;
      if (arr[a][b] == 0) {
         while((arr[a][(b+c)] == 0) && ((b+c)!=(arr[a].length-1))) {
            c++;
         }
         addBar(b, a, c); // Use these values in another function...
         b = b + c;
      } else {
         b++;
      }
   }
}
```

Problem: `b < arr[a].length;` does not get respected and loops again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: while in a loop in a loop

Comment: Use your debugger to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling this:

```
while ((arr[a][(b + c)] == 0) && ((b + c) != (arr[a].length - 1)))
```

There's arr[a][(b + c)] hidden in it, and c is always equals 1.
So your b == 2 at the time the last for-loop starts, all is well, it enters the loop, and the you're accessing b+c element (2+1), but there's only 3 elements in the inner array, maximum index shouldn't be greater than 2!

There's your bug. First loop:

```
  int c = 1;//b==0
  if (arr[a][b] == 0) {//arr[0][0] - correct
     while((arr[a][(b+c)] == 0) && ((b+c)!=(arr[a].length-1))) {
        c++; //c == 2
     }
     addBar(b, a, c); // Use these values in another function...
     b = b + c; //b == 0 + 2 == 2
  } else {
     b++;
  }
```

Second loop:

```
  int c = 1;//b== 2
  if (arr[a][b] == 0) {//arr[0][2] - correct
     while((arr[a][(b+c)] == 0) //ERROR!!! b+c == 3!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your second for loop

`for(int b = 0; b < arr[a].length;) {`

you should do it like this

`for(int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++) {` - You forgot the b++

Comment: I am manually increasing b near the end of the for-loop as might need to be increased by `c`, that is what the `if()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; /*you're not incrementing b*/)
```

So b will always be 0. Change it to:

```
for(int b = 0; b < arr[a].length; b++)
```

Comment: I am manually increasing b near the end of the for-loop as might need to be increased by `c`, that is what the `if()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

b+c gets out of array

```
if(b+c<arr[a].length)
      {
           while((arr[a][(b+c)] == 0) && ((b+c)!=(arr[a].length-1))) 
           {        
               c++;
       }
      }
```

I think you wanted to do that in the condition of while loop such that

```
((b+c)!=(arr[a].length-1)))
```

But this doesn't mean that. You can still be out of array.

And also you forgot the ++b increment in for loop like mentioned by others.